# Alternative for CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: c, sqlite, virtual

According to *CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE* [syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html), *IF NOT EXISTS* clause is [not available](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg52298.html).

How should I handle the case when the virtual table already exists without using *DROP TABLE IF EXISTS*?

I want to use rtree and fts module.

Comment: Why is there a c tag on this?

Comment: It is because I am using the C API of SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now supported since sqlite 3.7.11.

[changelog](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = ?
```

Then bind the virtual table name to your statement and call sqlite3_step().  If you get SQLITE_ROW back, then your table exists.  To be certain that it is a virtual table, check the `rootpage` column for '0'.

Comment: That is what I ended up using. the `type` for rtree virtual table is still a `table` though (sqlite 3.7.4). I also use use an immediate transaction to cover the checking and creating virtual table.

Comment: I've edited the solution here to select only the virtual tables.  You can check that this corresponds to your version by looking in the source file vacuum.c.